# View installed programs on remote machine?

Tags: network-monitoring

I was wondering if there is an easy and lightweight method to viewing what programs are installed on a remote machine?  I am tempted to use Spiceworks but I would like something more lightweight like a script.  I have been playing around with WMIC a little and can get a list of programs for my computer but I don't know if I can do the same with it for a remote computer.  Any ideas?

Edit:  Sorry that I forgot the OS, we are using mostly Windows XP and 7, I use Windows 7.  I am looking for something to be run in the background without a user that is currently using the computer knowing.  I would like to be able to do it during the workday while people are working and do so without interrupting them.  I do appreciate the Linux answers since I am trying to learn more about Linux and plan to personally change over sometime.

Comment: It would help to know the OS of the machine.

Comment: Why just programs? There may be other copyrighted material on the system (font files and mp3s are obvious cases)

Comment: @symcbean My main reason to ask is for licensing.  We have a couple programs that we only have a hand full of licenses for and I need to figure out where the programs are installed so I can determine if I can uninstall it somewhere so another user can use the program or if I need to purchase a new license.  The other stuff I will look into at a later point.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use one of the Sysinternals tools **PSinfo:**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550

> PsInfo v1.77 - Local and remote system information viewer Copyright
>   (C) 2001-2009 Mark Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> PsInfo returns information about a local or remote Windows NT/2000/XP
>   system.
>
> Usage: psinfo [-h] [-s] [-d] [-c [-t delimiter]] [filter]
>   [\computer[,computer[,..]]|@file [-u Username [-p Password]]]
>
> ```
>  -u        Specifies optional user name for login to
>            remote computer.
>  -p        Specifies password for user name.
>  -h        Show installed hotfixes.
>  -s        Show installed software.
>  -d        Show disk volume information.
>  -c        Print in CSV format
>  -t        The default delimiter for the -c option is a comma,
>            but can be overriden with the specified character. Use
>            "\t" to specify tab.
>  filter    Psinfo will only show data for the field matching the
> ```
>
> filter.
>                  e.g. "psinfo service" lists only the service pack
>   field.
>        computer  Direct PsInfo to perform the command on the remote
>                  computer or computers specified. If you omit the
>   computer
>                  name PsInfo runs the command on the local system,
>                  and if you specify a wildcard (\*), PsInfo runs the
>                  command on all computers in the current domain.
>        @file     PsInfo will run against the computers listed in the
>   file
>                  specified.

Issuing

PSinfo -s \\computername

will tell you what is installed on a remote computer.

Answer (score 11):

On an rpm-based Linux distribution, you could run the following:

```
ssh <user-who-can-run-rpm>@<remote.host> 'rpm -qa | sort'
```

For a deb-based distribution, pass this to the ssh command:

```
'dpkg-query -l | sort'
```

For Gentoo (per a supplied comment from [Monksy](https://serverfault.com/users/20480/monksy)):

```
'qpkg -I | sort'
```

For Solaris:

```
'pkginfo -i | sort'
```

And on AIX:

```
'lslpp -a all | sort'
```

Comment: Gentoo: If you have gentoolkit installed on gentoo you can find out all of the installed packages with:   "qpkg -I"

Comment: Can I use this on a Linux machine to view information on a Windows machine or is it just for Linux to Linux?

Comment: @Mobojo - not sure if you can run a similar command from a *nix machine to a Windows one; you should certainly be able use any ssh client to run these commands from any originating machine to *nix, though

Answer (score 6):

WMIC can be used remotely, by default, with an account that is part of Administrators group. You can delegate read-only WMI access to a normal user.

SNMP can be used too - you just need to configure a read-only community. You need to browse hrSWInstalled table: `snamwalk -c public -v2c server_IP hrSWInstalled`

See also: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Here is a PowerShell script that will connect to the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Uninstall registry key, pull the keys, get their display names and send to a text file.

```
$temparray=@()
$MachineName = 'somecomputername'
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::'LocalMachine', $MachineName)

#connect to the needed key :

$regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("software\Microsoft\Windows\currentversion\uninstall\" )

#and list the properties :

$programs = $regkey.GetSubKeyNames()
foreach ($program in $programs)
{   
    $regKey2 = $regKey.OpenSubKey($program)

    $temparray +=  $regKey2.GetValue("DisplayName")
}
$temparray |Sort-Object |Out-File -FilePath "C:\testinstalledprograms.txt" -Force
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a million programs that will do this. Some more easy and lightweight than others.

Here's just one of the innumerable programs that do this:

http://managepc.net/

Answer (score 1):

If it's a windows machine, you can run "WinAudit" (free, just search for it) on a scheduled job. It generates HTML or text reports and such, of which you can save to a network drive and view from a remote computer.

OR:

Remote desktop. You connect, and use it as if it were a local machine. Works in *nix too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI from powershell:

> gwmi win32_product -ComputerName Computer1